# Segmentation fault trying to install openmpi

Tags: c, linux, mpi, openmpi

I'm trying to install openmpi but after different attempts I still can't use it.

This is the [last guide](http://sysads.co.uk/2014/05/install-open-mpi-1-8-ubuntu-14-04-13-10/) I followed. I simply copied and paste each command line.

Here is what I obtained from my terminal when I run: `mpirun`

```
timmy@timmy-Lenovo-G50-80 ~/openmpi-1.8.1 $ mpirun
[timmy-Lenovo-G50-80:21817] *** Process received signal ***
[timmy-Lenovo-G50-80:21817] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[timmy-Lenovo-G50-80:21817] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[timmy-Lenovo-G50-80:21817] Failing at address: 0x7fab73035000
[timmy-Lenovo-G50-80:21817] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10340)[0x7fab73e20340]
[timmy-Lenovo-G50-80:21817] [ 1] /home/timmy/.openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_shmem_mmap.so(+0x1886)[0x7fab72e32886]
[timmy-Lenovo-G50-80:21817] [ 2] /home/timmy/.openmpi/lib/libopen-pal.so.13(opal_shmem_base_select+0x38)[0x7fab740d6b38]
[timmy-Lenovo-G50-80:21817] [ 3] /home/timmy/.openmpi/lib/libopen-pal.so.13(opal_init+0x1a2)[0x7fab74057cd2]
[timmy-Lenovo-G50-80:21817] [ 4] mpirun[0x403db1]
[timmy-Lenovo-G50-80:21817] [ 5] mpirun[0x40361d]
[timmy-Lenovo-G50-80:21817] [ 6] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7fab73a6cec5]
[timmy-Lenovo-G50-80:21817] [ 7] mpirun[0x403539]
[timmy-Lenovo-G50-80:21817] *** End of error message ***
Errore di segmentazione
```

So I reboot and now I obtain only this:

```
mpirun: error while loading shared libraries: libopen-rte.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What I have to do to make works mpi on linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include `/home/timmy/.openmpi/lib`. Specifically, you have to put those two lines from the guide you've followed:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/$USER/.openmpi/bin"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/$USER/.openmpi/lib/"
```

into your shell's initialisation file.

As to the first error, it occurs somewhere during the initialisation of the `mmap` shmem component of Open MPI and could indicate problems with your build. Try removing `/home/timmy/.openmpi` and rebuilding again. Or even try installing the library using your system's package manager - a more or less recent version of Open MPI is available in the package repository of virtually every distribution.

Comment: +1 to to "use your system's package manager".  That should always be preferred to building from source unless you have a good reason not to.  (When I build from source, I usually use Debian's packaging so I can install the result sanely; I recommend others do something similar).

Comment: @TobySpeight, that's true about `$HOME`, most notably on OS X, but should be fine in that particular case.

Comment: @TobySpeight How can I intall from sys manager? I am using linux mint 17.3, there's no package ompi or openmpi

Comment: @Timmy - if the package isn't available, I'd call that "a good reason not to".  I don't know Mint, but in Debian and Ubuntu, `aptitude search openmpi`indicates that there's `libopenmpi-dev` (for development) and `openmpi-bin` (for the runtime).  It may be that building from source is your only option, but do check.

Comment: Linux Mint does not seem to include Open MPI in its packages, but it borrows packages from Ubuntu and Debian, so one should be able to grab the package from one of those distributions and install it using `dpkg -i ...`

Comment: @TobySpeight I tried to install both: openmpi-bin and libopenmpi-dev but I am still not able to execute [THIS](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/comp/unix/farm/mpi_and_openmp.html)

Comment: @Timmy, would you care to elaborate on "not able to execute"?

Comment: Ok, no need to elaborate, I guess. The answer to my question lies in your other question about removing Open MPI.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

https://www.open-mpi.org/community/lists/users/2011/02/15759.php

quoted from URL:

> if you're using a hostfile to launch across multiple machines, ensure that your shell startup files (e.g., .bashrc) are setup to set your LD_LIBRARY_PATH properly.