# Remove all previous version MPI and reinstall correctly it

Tags: linux, mpi, openmp, openmpi

First of all: I'm on linux mint 17.3 x64

What I've done so far:

- [Guide to install Open MPI 1.8](http://sysads.co.uk/2014/05/install-open-mpi-1-8-ubuntu-14-04-13-10/)
- [Guide to install MPI](https://jetcracker.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/how-to-install-mpi-in-ubuntu/)
- Attemp to remove MPI executing: `sudo apt-get install libcr-dev mpich2 mpich2-doc` (Actually the should be not installed)

What I can see from terminal:

**output of:** `echo $PATH`

```
/path/to/mpj//bin:/home/timmy/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/timmy/.openmpi/bin
```

(I immagine that I've to remove `/path/to/mpj/` (not exists) and `/home/timmy/.openmpi/bin` (I want to remove previous version of ompi))

**output of:**  `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

```
(nothing)
```

Really, doesn't appear anything!

**output of** `mpirun`

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun could not find anything to do.

It is possible that you forgot to specify how many processes to run
via the "-np" argument.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Why I want to remove Open MPI and reinstall it**

- I've a project to do using both MPI and OpenMP and with the actual installation of MPI I cannot compile using the following command: `mpicc -openmp "test_omp.c" -o "test_omp"`. It gives me the following error: `Not defined function omp_get_thread_num();` and moreover, it ignore my `#pragma` commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are giving the compiler the wrong option to enable the OpenMP support. `-openmp` is only understood by the (commercial) Intel compiler, which is probably the tool-set installed on the site you've referred to in your other question. Most Linux distributions come with GCC and one is to assume that `mpicc` will use GCC (check with `mpicc -showme`).

The option to enable OpenMP support in GCC is `-fopenmp` (notice the `f`).

Comment: You are right! Now it compiles well, but when I execute the program MPI gives me segmentation fault as [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36432344/segmentation-fault-trying-to-install-openmpi)

Comment: Finally I succeeded in unistalling all previos attempts of installation of open mpi following [this guide](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues/600) (Points 2 and 3) Now everything works great!